# JPA Hibernate - How to save two objects from two entities that are connected

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, netbeans, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities: Account and Profile. They are connected with an One To One relationship.

**Account Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private Profile profile;

    ...

}
```

**Profile Enity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Account account;

    ...

}
```

The problem is when I try to save in database, a new object from Account and a new object from Profile and connect them. Something like this:

```
Account account = new Account();
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.setAccount(account);
account.setProfile(profile);

accountRepository.save(account);
profileRepository.save(profile);
```

Of course this doesn't work. After searching for a solution I found that I must use persist method and Transactions. However I haven't found how to use them. I tried to use EntityManager and create a `persistence.xml` file, but spring doesn't find it (I put it in directory: src/main/resources/Meta-INF).

My question is: Is there a simpler way to save both of the objects (without having to create new xml files etc.)? And if there isn't what exactly do I have to do, in order to make it work?

I use spring with hibernate and mysql, in Netbeans with Maven.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved it !
The problem was that the `CascadeType.All` property was in the wrong place. It should be in the Account Entity. Also, the `profileRepository.save(profile)` is not needed because the cascade of the Account manages the save of the profile. I also had some issues when I tried to show (with JSON) an account, with forever recursion, which I solved thanks to [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18288939/7053344) (`@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference`).

So now my code looks like this:

**Account Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
public class Account {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="profile_id")
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Profile profile;

    ...

}
```

**Profile Entity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "profile_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="profile")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Account account;

    ...

}
```

And for the save in database:

```
Account account = new Account();
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.setAccount(account);
account.setProfile(profile);

accountRepository.save(account);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change save order. Account entity cannot be created before profile.

```
Account account = new Account();
Profile profile = new Profile();
profile.setAccount(account);
account.setProfile(profile);

profileRepository.save(profile);
accountRepository.save(account);
```

Comment: Yes but Profile entity cannot be created before Account too. They both have the other entity in them.